# Im making a Many to Many relationship in SQLAlchemy. How do I solve my intergrity error?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I have 2 classes and I am making an association table via the relationship method.

```
class channel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'channel'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    attribute2 = Column(Integer)

    def __init__(self,channel):
        self.id    = channel.get('id', None)
        self.attribute2 = channel.get('attribute2', None)

class subscriptionpack(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'subscriptionpack'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    title = Column(String(45))

    channels = relationship('channel', secondary=subscriptionpack_channel, backref='subscription_packs', lazy = 'dynamic')

    def __init__(self,subscriptionpack):
        self.id = subscriptionpack['id']
        self.title = subscriptionpack['title'] 

subscriptionpack_channel = Table('subscriptionpack_channel', Base.metadata,
        Column('channel_id', Integer, ForeignKey("channel.id")),
        Column('ss_pack_id', Integer, ForeignKey("subscriptionpack.id"))
    )

   def example_main():
        session = sessionmaker(bind=self.db)

        for ch in channel_list:
            ch_obj = channel(ch)
            for ss_pack in ch['subscriptionpack']:
                ch_obj.subscription_packs.append(ss_pack)

            session.add(ch_obj)
        session.commit()
        session.close()
```

I get :

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError)
>   (1062, "Duplicate entry '161' for key 'PRIMARY'") [SQL: u'INSERT INTO
>   subscriptionpack

I have been successful using `session.merge(ch_obj)` but I do not want to update database if primary key is already in there.

Channels have many subscriptions.
I want to add entry into the association table via the channel object without automatically updating the `subscriptionpack` table. Is that possible? Would that be the right approach?

```
Example:
1. channel1 has subscriptions 1 and 2
2. channel2 has subscriptions 1 and 2
3. channel3 has subscriptions 1 and 3
```

Comment: Well you're creating new `channel` objects (and `subscriptionpack` objects, I'm assuming, since it's not clear from the example what `ss_pack` is) and adding them into the session, so of course SQLAlchemy is going to do a bunch of inserts for you. If you know an instance is already in the DB, you should query for it instead.

Comment: ss_pack is a subscriptionpack object. So @univerio your suggesting that I query for it and add that object that I retrieve from the query. This would stop the duplicate entry error. Is this the correct understanding?

Comment: Well, where are you getting the `ss_pack` object from?

Comment: I just created it from data outside the database. should I be loading those objects into the database first then using those for the creation of my channel objects?

Comment: No. You need to think about what data you currently have in your database. Whatever data you have you should be querying instead of adding anew.

Comment: Its a brand new database.  This would be the initial batch of things being loaded.

Comment: What you currently have in the database refers to at the point the `INSERT` query is executed. That means if you have added new objects before the insertion, *even if your database is empty when you started the whole thing*, you will need to query for it. There's an additional wrinkle where if you haven't flushed yet your query won't return anything. In this case, do `session.query(channel).get(<primary key>)`. The key here is that you cannot add two different instances of the same model with the same primary key to the session; you need to reuse a previously created instance the second time.